# Derivative of $\frac{1}{(x+1)^{k-1}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How is it that the derivative of $\frac{1}{(x+1)^{k-1}}$ is $-\frac{k-1}{x^k}$ where $k$ is a parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wow, lots of eccentric notation in these answers. This is a simple problem. Just rewrite the reciprocal as a negated exponent and apply the chain rule:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{(x+1)^{k-1}}\right)'=\left((x+1)^{-k+1}\right)'
$$
$$
=(-k+1)(x+1)^{-k}\cdot(x+1)'
$$
$$
=(-k+1)(x+1)^{-k}\cdot 1
$$
$$
=(-k+1)\frac{1}{(x+1)^k}\cdot 1
$$
$$
=-\frac{k-1}{(x+1)^k}
$$

for $k\neq 1$ (if $k =1$, the expression is constant where defined and so its derivative is zero there).

Answer (score 6):

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{(x+1)^{k-1}}=\frac{d}{dx}(x+1)^{-(k-1)}=\frac{d}{dx}(x+1)^{-k+1}=(-k+1)(x+1)^{-k}$$

Answer (score 2):

Using Chain Rule [(1)](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChainRule.html) or [(2)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule),

$$\frac{d\left[\dfrac1{(x+1)^{k-1}}\right]}{dx}=\frac{d\left[(x+1)^{-(k-1)}\right]}{d(x+1)}\cdot\frac{d(x+1)}{dx}$$

Comment: Thank you. I'm not that familiar with this notation. Can you use an alternative one please?

Comment: @Elimination, Please find the links in the answer

Comment: @EulCan, Rectified

Comment: @Elimination basically $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}$$. Plus this would of been the way I would of approached it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the very basic formula as well, however; you will need to use the @lab's way for some parts: $$\left(\frac{u}{v}\right)'=\frac{u'v-uv'}{v^2}$$ where `'` means differentiation with respect to $x$.